# How do I delete an empty Framelayout in Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I created a fragmentactivity and have a Drawerlayout in the main-layout. Inside is a ListView (Optionsmenu) and a Framelayout, that i want to fill with different fragment topic.

When starting the activity there are two options for the first screen, depending on existing data from the user or not. So I want to show different content in the framelayout.

It works, so the two different fragments are shown correctly as the first screen, but if the user hits the hardware back-button, he returns to that empty page. But I want to ask him simple, if he wants to close the app (starting an new AlertDialog.Builder()).

So I wonder how to do that, hide the white screen and when he hit the backButton and the only fragment left is the empty one, he should get the question if he wants to leave the app.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
FrameLayoutName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It will delete the FrameLayout along with space.

Revert Process if you want

```
FrameLayoutName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: that is not what i was looking for. when I go back, there is still the same white screen like before. That did not removed the event from the backstack neither skipped the view.

Answer (score 0):

try this..,you can pass the intent in delete code for returning to previous activity...,
    and all of this you have to write on onBackPress() method.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Campaign_Details.this);

                    builder.setMessage("WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO?");
                    builder.setNegativeButton("DELETE",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
   //code for delete
}

builder.setNeutralButton("CANCEL",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                            }
                            // DO NOTHING
                        });

                builder.setCancelable(false);
                AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
                alertdialog.show();

                return true;
```

Comment: yeah, i thought about onBackPress(), but that event is fired every time i click on the backButton, it should only be fired, when the framelayout is empty. This is the first case after starting the activity. After that the framelayout get filled with content. so when the user clicked on back, he will see the white screen. But when the user is inside a fragment, he can swap to anotherone, so he should be able to press the backbutton.

Comment: then for starting you can pass your this AlertDialog inside 
if(yourFragment ==null){  
.
.}
else{
}

Comment: it is not null, its just empty... has an id and height and width, but no content

Comment: see this, http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/

Comment: the problem is, I have to declare an default screen, which I get after inflating. The process is, starting activity, looking for data and decide which fragment should be loaded. with that <fragment> instead of Framelayout, i will have the new layout above the old one. Looking very strange

Comment: so on taking note of that data,you can use if condition,i think

Comment: Add public method in your fragment that check if is content empty, so you can write in onBackPressed(): if(yourFragment.isEmptyContent()){ //do your work here }else{ super.onBackPressed(); }

Comment: Do you know how i can check if there is a Layout inside my Layout? That would be great and an option for me